# Mysql functions output as part of where condition in clause

Tags: mysql

Created a new function in mysql using GROUP_CONCAT.
My Function as follows:

```
    CREATE  FUNCTION `Get_customerCodes`(customer_id int(11)) 
    RETURNS varchar(500) CHARSET utf8
    BEGIN
    Declare Result VARCHAR(1000);
        set Result =  (select GROUP_CONCAT(concat('\'', customer_code,'\'') 
              SEPARATOR ',') from customers 
         where customer_id in (customer_id));
   Return Result;
   END
```

when i call above function it returns comma seperated customerscodes like this
'1','2','3','4'.

But I need to use the output **Get_customerCodes** functions result in where clause **IN** condition.

***Test Case:***

```
 select * from my_table where customer_code IN (Get_customerCodes(CAST('1002' AS SIGNED)));
```

**Expectation:**

On executing above query, mysql should give me the results based on the functions output.**Actual query would look like bellow**

**select * from my_table where customer_code IN ('1','2','3','4');**

***Questions:***

- Is it possible to use mysql function output as part of where
  condition **IN** clause.
- If possible provide an example. If not possible give me an alternative
  solution.

Comment: `RETURNS varchar (500) <> Declare Result VARCHAR (1000);` Caution, your result may be truncated. You can use a [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it with the help of `FIND_IN_SET`:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(customer_code, Get_customerCodes(1002));`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points to consider:

- `The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable,`, see [12.19.1 Aggregate (GROUP BY) Function Descriptions :: GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).
- Avoid naming the parameters of the function as columns of your tables, see [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs :: Name Conflicts within Stored Routines](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html).

An option using [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table`, `customers`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `Get_customerCodes`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers`(
    ->   `customer_id` INT NOT NULL,
    ->   `customer_code` VARCHAR(2),
    ->   PRIMARY KEY(`customer_id`, `customer_code`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table`(
    ->   `id` INT NOT NULL,
    ->   `customer_code` VARCHAR(2)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION `Get_customerCodes`(`_customer_id` INT)
    -> RETURNS VARCHAR(500) CHARSET utf8
    ->   RETURN (
    ->     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('\'', `customer_code`, '\'')
    ->            SEPARATOR ',')
    ->     FROM `customers`
    ->     WHERE `customer_id` IN (`_customer_id`)
    ->   );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `customers`
    ->   (`customer_id`, `customer_code`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   (1002, 1), (1002, 2),
    ->   (1002, 3), (1002, 4);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO `my_table`
    ->   (`id`, `customer_code`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   (1, 1), (2, 2),
    ->   (3, 3), (4, 4);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SET @`query` := CONCAT('
    '> SELECT *
    '> FROM `my_table`
    '> WHERE `customer_code` IN (',
    -> `Get_customerCodes`(CAST('1002' AS SIGNED)), ')');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`query` `to_execute`;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| to_execute                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 
SELECT *
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `customer_code` IN ('1','2','3','4') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`query`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE `stmt`;
+----+---------------+
| id | customer_code |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | 1             |
|  2 | 2             |
|  3 | 3             |
|  4 | 4             |
+----+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i81HTLmoMpwkcw7dirEJ4u/0).